# Azure DNS Config for Custom Root Domain - CDN not being used

Tags: azure, dns, azure-cdn

I am having problems with my Azure static website not using the CDN that is set up. I have been looking as the Q&As here and also Microsoft docs but I still can't see what I have done wrong. I have spent hours trying to resolve it and think I am down to guessing now.

```
Azure DNS
Microsoft Standard CDN
Custom Root Domain      example.com
CDN End Point           https://example.azureedge.net/
```

So basically the setup is Namecheap Domain with Custom DNS being handled in Azure with the following records.

```
|          Name          | Type         | TTL         | Value                                       | Alias   resource type     | Alias target     |
|:----------------------:|--------------|-------------|---------------------------------------------|---------------------------|------------------|
|             @          |     A        |     3600    |         -                                   |     Azure CDN             |     example      |
|     cdnverify.alias    |     CNAME    |     3600    |         cdnverify.example.azureedge.net     |                           |                  |
|     cdnverify          |     CNAME    |     3600    |         cdnverify.example.azureedge.net     |                           |                  |
|     cdnverify.www      |     CNAME    |     3600    |         cdnverify.example.azureedge.net.    |                           |                  |
|     www                |     CNAME    |     7200    |         example.azureedge.net               |                           |                  |
|     example.com        |     CNAME    |     300     |         example.azureedge.net               |                           |                  |
```

GTMetrix shows that my domain is not using a CDN but does (obv.) when i test directly to the end point https://example.azureedge.net/

Am I missing DNS records or do I just have them set up incorrectly? I am at a loss as to what is serving my content as there aren't any references to anything other than the CDN endpoint.

Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: It seems to me that if a CNAME for "www" is setting up the subdomain "*www*.example.com", then a CNAME for "example.com" should be setting up the subdomain "*example.com*.example.com". And if your alias is set to "example", then that would reference the subdomain "example.example.com". Try updating the alias target to "www".

Comment: Hi, If I am understanding correctly I do'nt think I can. The alias in the A record points an Azure CDN resource which happens to have the name example. I should have made that clearer in my example.. Also wverything redirects to the root as I do not want www

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see there are two extra DNS records according to your requirements that you want to add custom domains `www.example.com` and `example.com`. You can remove it.

`cdnverify.alias    |     CNAME    |     3600    |         cdnverify.example.azureedge.net`

```
example.com        |     CNAME    |     300     |         example.azureedge.net
```

When you add an alias record for root domain `example.com` in Azure DNS.
[image]

It will generate a `@` name A record and `cdnverify` name CNAME record.

[image]

In addition, you could clear cached content on the CDN edge servers by purging the CDN endpoint when you validate it. For more information, see [Purge an Azure CDN endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-purge-endpoint).

Comment: Thanks that is useful. I will check out the Purge link now. I think its possible the DNS points to the CDN OK but that for some reason the CDN is not serving all content??? I don't know much about it but I have just see that the HTML page returns X-Cache: TCP_HIT whilst all other resources return X-Cache: TCP_MISS which looks to be Azure saying the CDN was not used.

Comment: Is there any [caching policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-standard-rules-engine-reference)? Also, not all files or pages will be cached by CDN and you also need to check the `Cache-Control` or `max-age` in the page. See [how caching works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-how-caching-works).

Comment: There is a caching policy in the Rules Engine:  Cache Behaviour=Override 20 days for everything. I am planing to customise that per type in the near future. I can see now that images that were not being served by the CDN look like they noew are based on the response headers: **cache-control: public, max-age=1728000** **server: Windows-Azure-Web/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0** **x-cache: TCP_HIT**

Comment: The strange thing is that when I use my custom domain the CDN is still not recognised by GTMETRIX (or other a number of other tools) but it is when I use the EndPoint URL directly it is. Maybe that is something for another question??

Comment: Thanks very much for the help.